# How to allow -999 to 999 numbers only in input box in JavaScript with keypress event?

Tags: javascript, input, keypress

I am trying to restrict my input box in javascript to have numbers only -999 to 999 with keypress event. But somehow this is failing, can someone help me with this. This is what i have tried so far:-

```
if(((event.originalEvent.target.value.indexOf("-") > -1) && event.originalEvent.target.value.length === 4) || ((event.originalEvent.target.value.indexOf("-") < 0) && event.originalEvent.target.value.length === 3)) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to have a input textbox in which user can enter numbers only and that too from -999 to 999. I cannot use number type with min range and maxrange.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this

```
<input type="number" name="yourName" min="-999" max="999">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<script>
function allowRange(min, max, input) {
   if(input.value == '-' || (isNaN(input.value) == false && parseInt(input.value) >= min && parseInt(input.value) <= max)) {
   //do nothing
   }
   else {
      input.value = '';
   }
}
</script>

<input type="text" oninput="allowRange(-999, 999, this);">
```

It will automatically erase any input not within the range.

Comment: This is erasing the input if not in range. I dont want to erase, just block the user if input becomes 999.